# How can i change language google assistant SDK using gRPC?

Tags: android, grpc, google-assistant-sdk

i trying to make application using google assistant sdk.

i have success talking with google assistant in english... but i don't know how change language.

i want talk with google assistant using korean, but i think google assistant sdk is not support change language(now defalut value is english).

and google assistant sdk official webpage does not refer to how to change language. 
-https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview

is there anyone who knows solution, please save me.

already very thankyou.

Comment: Afaict the Assist() rpc function has a language code field. Have you tried this? https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/rpc/google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2#google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2.DialogStateIn

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Assistant SDK service, you can change the language by setting language code here.

```
@click.option('--lang', show_default=True,
              metavar='<language code>',
              default='en-US',
              help='Language code of the Assistant')
```

https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/pushtotalk.py#L235

For Assistant SDK library, you can only set language from Assistant App, and Korean is not supported on 2018.1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :=)